# Static Method & Multithreading Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know that static methods aren't always thread safe but if designed properly they are thread safe because internal variables are reinitialized every run...

Below is some code I found here but it looks thread safe because all resources are internalized within the method. Yet it still throws a null pointer sometimes when it tries to release resources (I've commented the line).

```
 public static string XmlHttpRequest(string urlString, string xmlContent)
 {
     string response = null;
     HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
     HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;//Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class

     //Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL.
     httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlString);

     try
     {
         byte[] bytes;

         bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlContent);

         //Set HttpWebRequest properties
         httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
         httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
         httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

         using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
         {
             //Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream 
             requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
             requestStream.Close();//Close stream
         }

         //Sends the HttpWebRequest, and waits for a response.
         httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

         if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
         {
             //Get response stream into StreamReader
             using (Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
             {
                 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                     response = reader.ReadToEnd();
             }
         }

         httpWebResponse.Close();//Close HttpWebResponse
     }
     catch (WebException we){}
     catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }
     finally
     {
         httpWebResponse.Close();
         //Here is the null in the line above

         httpWebResponse = null;
         httpWebRequest = null;
     }

     return response;
 }
```

So for some reason the line I commented in the code is throwing a null because the httpWebResponse is null. I assume it's something to do with threads using this method. It only happens SOMETIMES.

Comment: I need to ask a dumb question. What if you *don't* declare the method as static? Do you still get the errors? (I strongly guess you will not). What does this indicate?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? My suspicion is with D Stanley's answer that it might of been an exception thrown before `httpWebResponse` gets assigned a value.

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with whether it is static or not. Finally is always called, even after the catch block. My guess is that httpWebResponse is null. Simply check if it is null before closing.

Comment: I was already aware that it can throw a webexception I decided not to handle it. Probably the issue. Case closed. Silly mistake not sure why i deserve the down votes but ok thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with threads.  You are likely getting an exception *before* `httpWebResponse` is assigned a value.  Since you are swallowing any `WebException` it is entirely possible for `httpWebResponse` to be null without you knowing that an exception occurred.

Also your *other* exception handler is throwing a *new* vanilla exception with just the message included.  You lose all other information such as the base exception type and stack trace.  You *could* just rethrow the original exception but that's the same thing as not having another `catch` block at all.

I would:

- remove both `catch` blocks (or at least the second on)
- wrap the `httpWebResponse` in a `using` block (then it will be closed automatically if an exception is thrown).
- check to see if `httpWebResponse` before calling `Close` on it. (note that if you wrap it in a using you don't have to close it, so you don't have to check if it is null)

Also, setting `httpWebResponse` and `httpWebRequest` to null is pointless as well since they will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the method exits.